# Create web mapping application. Leaflet or OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, leaflet, openlayers

I am creating a complex web mapping application (with size files 500 MB GeoJSon and Shapefile), and I use Javascript, GeoServer and Postgis,

I started to create the application with Leaflet, I'm documented a little more about Leaflet, I found that  Leaflet is less stable and less powerful with Geoserver and large files.

I have two questions please:

1/ I decided to create an other application  and use OpenLayers, what do you think about  OpenLayer s? for this kind of application (Complexe application).

2/ I also need the backend part, I do not have an idea of ​​the language that I'm going to use, what I have to use NodeJS or PHP for this kind of application ?

Thank you,

Comment: For large complex apps, I'd use Openlayers over Leaflet. I find it more powerful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the second question what do you think about PHP and NodeJS for Backend ?

Comment: We are using Java for the backend. But it's an old backend. Haven't tried any of those with map apps, I cannot tell.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're in the planning phase, and it also sounds like you're looking for free, but ESRI is the way to go. Their JS API is vast and will do anything you need it to do. Use AGS online for $500/yr for your backend, and you will be able to create and do absolutely anything. https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-online/pricing, https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/

Comment: Thank you all for your answer, I found a solution very used in open source, it's to use GeoTools in Java that will allow me to create an interface for connection also with J2ee. :)

Answer (score 0):

- I would strongly advise against Leaflet. The main reason for that is that Leaflet doesn't have the concept of Features. Any feature added to leaflet is added as a separate layer. So a feature is a layer in Leaflet. Features are inherent to GIS applications that is why they exist in other GIS libraries, applications and GeoFormats like: ESRI JS API, OpenLayers, QGis, Udig, GeoJSON, shapefile, etc. So the reason for Leaflet not adhering to these concepts is unclear to me. Perhaps someone else can enlighten us?
- For the backend part, it really depends on what you want to do and the requirements you have. A backend can be written in almost any language. You can also use existing solutions like GeoServer, ArcGIS Server and MapServer, these servers support, in various degrees OGC standards like WMS/WFS/WMTS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
but why each feature is a separate layer?
yet we only use one map and we can integrate all layers into our map, isnt' it ?

By cons I want a open source thing, that's why I wanted to work with leaflet, and Esri is paying.

For the back-end, I want to create an authentication system to connect to the application at first time, but also to be able to store the polygons create on the map in the database, (To handle also the SQL queries)
I use WMS services too to display my overlay directly

Comment: I do not know why they add every feature separately as a layer.
But yes we define one map and add our layers into that map. A layer can consist of features or it can consist of other layers. If the layer consists of layers it is called a [LayerGroup](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Group-LayerGroup.html)
You could also make a simple REST service with Java and the [JTS library](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) and POST your geometries to your backend, manipulate them and store them. And you can make a GET service for requesting them, returning them as GeoJSON.

Comment: If you take a closer look at GeoTools, you will see that internally, GeoTools also uses the [JTS library](https://github.com/locationtech/jts). Cheers!